# Minus query / operator in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a Oracle 11g db. I  have Currency Table for which i have 182 records in the year 2013 and for the year 2014, i have 81 records. I have to get the difference 101 records from 2013. Missing / Difference records i have to insert into the year 2014.

I wonder whether my syntax is incorrect or any other method to generate the difference query.

```
SELECT 
a.CCYCD,
a.YEARNR
FROM CCYEXC a
WHERE  a.YEARNR = 2013

minus

SELECT 
a.CCYCD,
a.YEARNR
FROM CCYEXC a
WHERE  a.YEARNR = 2014;
```

Comment: What's the difference between YEARNR and YEAR_NR?

Comment: What happened when you executed the query? Did it not give you desired output?

Comment: @Multisync, YEARNR and YEAR_NR is my mistake. It has to be YEARNR.

Comment: @wasabi I was thinking the same, but I was assuming that was no mistake. It makes a big difference if it is. In addition, no need to display a variable if you tell it, it must only be one value.

Comment: MINUS would work, just do as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CCYCD
     , YEARNR
  FROM CCYEXC
 WHERE YEAR_NR = 2014
   AND CCYCD,YEARNR NOT IN 
           (
      SELECT CCYCD
           , YEARNR
        FROM CCYEXC
       WHERE YEAR_NR = 2013 
           );
```

Comment: I think you forgot brackets

Comment: I am sorry, Syntax is not working. Error as Invalid Relational Operator.

Comment: I cannot run this, but as Multisync mentions, it may miss out on brackets. What line number does he state having an error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of [MINUS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) is correct. When you want SET difference, MINUS is correct way to go. Note that some other databases use [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) keyword for this operation.

Following set operations are available.

- UNION (ALL)
- INTERSECT
- MINUS/EXCEPT

Comment: What do you mean, "other" databases ? The OP says : oracle11g

Comment: The usage of MINUS may be not correct as it also eliminates dublicates in the resulting set

Comment: It is supposed to that. It is a SET operation. a SET does not hold duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You only need to have the `CCYCD` column in the `SELECT` list in the `MINUS` query. Now, to insert this result into the table for year 2014, just write an i sert statement like this,

`INSERT INTO ccyexc`
    `SELECT ccycd, 2014 as "yearnr"`
    `FROM(`
       `<your MINUS query>`
    `);`

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS usually faster:

```
SELECT a.CCYCD, a.YEARNR
FROM CCYEXC a
WHERE  a.YEARNR = 2013
  and not exists (select 1 from CCYEXC b where b.YEARNR = 2014 and b.CCYCD = a.CCYCD);
```

Another option:

```
SELECT a.CCYCD, a.YEARNR
FROM CCYEXC a
WHERE  a.YEARNR = 2013
  and a.CCYCD not in (select distinct CCYCD from CCYEXC b where b.YEARNR = 2014);
```

Also you can use LEFT JOIN

MINUS doesn't work because both sets (subqueries) have different YEARNR (they don't intersect)

Comment: No, MINUS will work. Don't put the year column in the select list as it makes no sense in having different years which would never intersect. Look at my answer.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar MINUS from the question doesn't work. Of course in different cases it can be used. I've just pointed where the problem was

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way to write this is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT c.CCYCD,
FROM CCYEXC c
GROUP BY c.CCYCD
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.YEARNR = 2013 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.YEARNR = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Or, as others have suggested, a `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` clause.